# Java - subclass and superclass relationship

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I'm working on a homework assignment for my Java course and I'm completely lost. I guess I don't fully understand subclass and superclass relationships, but I'm trying my best to trudge along. The assignment asks us to do this:

The class Stock.java represents purchased shares of a given stock. You want to create a type of object for stocks which pay dividends.

The amount of dividends that each shareholder receives is proportional to the number of shares that person owns. Not every stock pays dividends, so you wouldn't want to add this functionality directly to the Stock class. Instead, you should create a new class called DividendStock that extends Stock and adds this new behavior.

Each DividendStock object will inherit the symbol, total shares, and total cost from the Stock superclass. You will need to add a field to record the amount of the dividends paid.

The dividend payments that are recorded should be considered to be profit for the stockholder. The overall profit of a DividendStock is equal to the profit from the stock's price plus any dividends. This amount is computed as the market value (number of shares times current price) minus the total cost paid for the shares, plus the amount of dividends paid.

Here is the stock.java file

```
/**
 * A Stock object represents purchases of shares of a 
 * company's stock.
 *
 */


public class Stock {
    
    private String symbol;
    private int totalShares;
    private double totalCost;
    
    /**
     * Initializes a new Stock with no shares purchased
     * @param symbol = the symbol for the trading shares
     */
    public Stock(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        totalShares = 0;
        totalCost = 0.0;
    }
    


    /**
     * Returns the total profit or loss earned on this stock
     * @param currentPrice = the price of the share on the stock exchange
     * @return
     */
    public double getProfit(double currentPrice) {
        double marketValue = totalShares * currentPrice;
        return marketValue - totalCost;
    }
    
    /**
     * Record purchase of the given shares at the given price
     * @param shares = the number of shares purchased
     * @param pricePerShare = the price paid for each share of stock
     */
    public void purchase(int shares, double pricePerShare) {
        totalShares += shares;
        totalCost += shares * pricePerShare;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public int getTotalShares() {
        return totalShares;
    }

    public void setTotalShares(int totalShares) {
        this.totalShares = totalShares;
    }

    public double getTotalCost() {
        return totalCost;
    }

    public void setTotalCost(double totalCost) {
        this.totalCost = totalCost;
    }
    

}
```

I have started working on a subclass called DividendStock.java, but I'm not sure what I'm missing and what I need to do to actually test if its working or not. Does anyone have any tips?

```
public class DividendStock extends Stock{
    private double dividends;
    private double profit;
    

    public DividendStock(String symbol){
        super(symbol);
        dividends = 0.0;
        profit = 0.0;
    }

    public double payDividend(double amountPerShare){
        dividends += amountPerShare*getTotalShares();
        return dividends;
    }
    
    public double profit(double amountPerShare) {
        profit = super.getProfit(profit) + payDividend(amountPerShare);
        return profit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One tip, keep it simple if you don't understand it, that way you learn it best. Here a working example for you.

```
class MySuperClass {
    protected String whoami;
    
    MySuperClass() {
        this.whoami = "I'm the Superclass";
    }
    
    void whoAmI() {
        System.out.println(whoami);
    }
}

class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {
    MySubClass() {
        super.whoami = "I'm the Subclass";
    }
}

public class TestWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySuperClass bigbro = new MySuperClass();
        MySubClass littlesis = new MySubClass();
        
        bigbro.whoAmI();
        littlesis.whoAmI();
    }
}
```